# Mascara de decimais em um ion-input do tipo "number"

Tags: ionic, angular, ionic2

Estou precisando fazer uma máscara de valores (9 digitos com 3 decimais), e quando o usuário começar a informar o valor, o campo coloque as virgulas e ponto de forma automatica, parecido com o que acontece hoje nos sistemas de banco, onde no campo temos o 0,00 e conforme vamos digitando o valor vai para a esquerda.

Exemplo: Quero informar R$ 12,67

Input: 0,00

0,01

0,12

1,26

12,67

Já tentei alternativas com libs externas, mas elas só tem efeito sobre campos com type "Text", e por estar desenvolvendo para um tablet, não quero que o teclado abra com as palavras, apenas números. Meu input type hoje é number, porém nos dispositivos da Samsung, não são listados a opção de "," ou ".", apenas o número.

Meu código está assim:

```
<ion-input type="number" #input name="quantidade" [(ngModel)]="quantidade" required></ion-input>
```

Comment: Utilize o `type` `tel`

Comment: Ainda não funciona @RobertoFagundes. Eu preciso que ele se comporte conforme o exemplo da questão.

Comment: Eu procurei fazer isso de várias formas, mas sempre topava com algum problema (ex: o usuário poder colar números ou clicar no meio do número e continuar a digitar). A solução que encontrei foi abrir um modal com uma espécie de calculadora para o usuário informar o valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi usando uma função mesmo e mudando o tipo do campo para "tel". Não é a melhor das maneiras, mas acredito que supra a necessidade por enquanto.

```
<ion-input type="tel" inputmode="numeric" min="0" max="1000" (keyup)="updateList($event)" [(ngModel)]="valor"> </ion-input>
```

------JS ------

```
updateList(ev){

this.valor = this.currencyFormatted(ev.target.value)

}



currencyFormatted(amount) {

  var formatedValue = amount;
  var real = '';
  var cents = '';
  var temp = [];
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var k = 0;

  formatedValue = this.clearString(formatedValue.toString(), "0123456789");

  if(formatedValue.length > 3) {

    real = formatedValue.substr(0, formatedValue.length - 3);
    real = "" + parseInt(real, 10);
    cents = formatedValue.substr(formatedValue.length - 3, 3);

    if(real.length > 3) {
      temp = [];
      for(i = real.length - 1, j = 1, k = 0; i > 0 ; i--, j++) {
        if((j % 3) == 0) {
          temp.push(real.substr(i, 3));
          k++;
        }
      }
      temp.reverse();
      real = real.substr(0, real.length - (3 * k)) + '.' + temp.join('.');
    }
    formatedValue = real + ',' + cents;
  }
  return formatedValue;
}



clearString(value, validCharacters) {
  var result = '';
  var index = -1;
  var i = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    index = validCharacters.indexOf(value.charAt(i));

   if(index > -1) {
      result += validCharacters.charAt(index);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```